# Posso fazer mais de 1 insert usando PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

Quero fazer mais de 1 insert usando PDO e um arquivo php, eu posso?
Exemplo:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,X-Prototype-Version,X-Requested-With');

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

include_once("conPDO.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data);

$msg  = $data->msg;
$idUsuario  = $data->idUsuario;
$idCep  = $data->idCep;
$nome  = $data->nome;
$foto ='';

$qryEnd=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM cep WHERE idCep=:idCep");
$qryEnd->bindValue("idCep", $idCep);
$qryEnd->execute();

while ($linha=$qryEnd->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $idCep  = $linha['idCep'];
        $uf = $linha['uf'];
        $cidade = utf8_encode($linha['cidade']);
        $bairro = utf8_encode($linha['bairro']);
        $logradouro = utf8_encode($linha['logradouro']);
}
$data = date('Y-m-d,H:m:s');

$diaEHora = explode(',', $data);
$data = $diaEHora[0];
$hora = $diaEHora[1];

$insereMsgLogra=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO avisosLogradouro (idAvisoLogradouro, idUsuario, estado, cidade, bairro, logradouro, msg, foto, data, hora) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$insereMsgLogra->bindValue(1, NULL); 
$insereMsgLogra->bindValue(2, $idUsuario); 
$insereMsgLogra->bindValue(3, $uf); 
$insereMsgLogra->bindValue(4, $cidade); 
$insereMsgLogra->bindValue(5, $bairro); 
$insereMsgLogra->bindValue(6, $logradouro); 
$insereMsgLogra->bindValue(7, $msg); 
$insereMsgLogra->bindValue(8, $foto);
$insereMsgLogra->bindValue(9, $data);
$insereMsgLogra->bindValue(10, $hora);
$insereMsgLogra->execute();

$insereMsgBairro=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO avisosBairro (idAvisoBairro, idUsuario, estado, cidade, bairro, msg, foto, data, hora) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$insereMsgBairro->bindValue(1, NULL); 
$insereMsgBairro->bindValue(2, $idUsuario); 
$insereMsgBairro->bindValue(3, $uf); 
$insereMsgBairro->bindValue(4, $cidade); 
$insereMsgBairro->bindValue(5, $bairro); 
$insereMsgBairro->bindValue(6, $msg); 
$insereMsgBairro->bindValue(7, $foto);
$insereMsgBairro->bindValue(8, $data);
$insereMsgBairro->bindValue(9, $hora);
$insereMsgBairro->execute() or die(print_r($insereMsgBairro->errorInfo()); 
?>
```

É possível fazer isso?
Pois tentei e só o primeiro funcionou.

No log do php mostra isso:

> [01-Feb-2016 19:49:09 Europe/Berlin] PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Sim é possível, não existem limites para o PDO :D

Comment: Veja qual é o erro do segundo insert, talvez seja de violação de algum campo uniq key.

Comment: Como vejo erros em PDO?

Comment: Faz, `$insereMsgBairro->execute() or die(print_r($insereMsgBairro->errorInfo());`

Comment: Beleza @rray, vou tentar

Comment: Olha, o erro que deu foi esse:
 http://localhost:8888/sistemas/sistemas_web/ionic/vcApp/www/php/enviaMsgLogra.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
Pelo visto é um erro no meu código php

Comment: Sim, coloca `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` no começo desse arquivo.

Comment: Já tenho isso no meu código

Comment: Só pelo log do apache dai.

Comment: No log do apache eu não encontrei, mas do php sim.
Coloquei na descrição do post a mensagem do log.

Comment: Coloca como texto que é mais fácil de ler, esse é o código completo?

Comment: Desculpe, mas como assim, colocar como texto?
Não, tem outros selects para buscar outros dados, tb

Comment: O erro está como uma imagem, não consigo ver.

Comment: Ahh sim, é um print que tirei... Vou mudar então

Comment: @rray, coloquei a mensagem de erro, do log, em texto, no post

Comment: Acho que encontrei o erro...

Comment: Achei um erro, mas não era esse o problema

Comment: Corrigi isso:
$insereMsgBairro->execute() or die(print_r($pdo->errorInfo()));

Faltava fechar 1 parêntese

Answer (score 0):

Seu `while` está encerrando antes de fazer qualquer insert.
Com isso o bloco de código referente ao insert é executado uma única vez.

```php
 while ($linha=$qryEnd->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- *
    A cada loop o valor das variáveis é atualizado, mas não é utilizado.
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
     $idCep  = $linha['idCep'];
     $uf = $linha['uf'];
     $cidade = utf8_encode($linha['cidade']);
     $bairro = utf8_encode($linha['bairro']);
     $logradouro = utf8_encode($linha['logradouro']);
 }

/* Seus blocos de insert estão depois do WHILE */

$insereMsgLogra=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO avisosLogradouro (idAvisoLogradouro, idUsuario, estado, cidade, bairro, logradouro, msg, foto, data, hora) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$insereMsgLogra->bindValue(1, NULL); 
$insereMsgLogra->bindValue(2, $idUsuario); 
$insereMsgLogra->bindValue(3, $uf); 
$insereMsgLogra->bindValue(4, $cidade); 
...
$insereMsgLogra->execute();
```

Espero ter ajudado...